# Formatting Issue when minimizing and re-sizing browser

Tags: html, css

I have a `navbar` at the top of my screen with elements on the left and right and when I resize the window left or right, I want the elements to push together until they hit, and then have the window start hiding it. Currently once my elements hit, it tries to take the text on the left of the `navbar` and stack it underneath. I used min-width on the list on the right and that worked fine, but min-width on the text on the right is just adding space between my logo and text

Sorry if this is confusing. I'm somewhat new to this so just trying to work through things.

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #a9a9a9;
margin: 0px;
padding: -10px;
}
/*Navigation Bar*/
#imglogo{
width: 75px;
height: 65px;
float:left;
display: inline;
margin-left:50px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
#Logo{
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#NavBackground {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #696969 0%, #5C5C5C 100%);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#696969;
    height:65px;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px #464646;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
#NavBackground ul { 
    padding: 0 0 0 30px; 
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-family:Montserrat;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #D1D1D1;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
#NavBackground ul li { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline; 
}
```

Div Setup

```
<div id="NavBackground"> 
        <img id="imglogo" src="bklogo.png"></img>
        <text id ="Logo">BCd<span style="color:#D1D1D1">3d</span><span style="font-size:12pt">.com</span></text>    
        <ul id="Sections">
            <li id="Home"><u>Home&nbsp;&nbsp;</u></li>
            <li id="About Me"><u>About Me&nbsp;&nbsp;</u></li>
            <li id="Images"><u>Images&nbsp;&nbsp;</u></li>
            <li id="Videos"><u>Videos&nbsp;&nbsp;</u></li>
            <li id="Contact"><u>Contact&nbsp;&nbsp;</u></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a min-width to #NavBackground will probably do the trick

Comment: Ahhhh that did the trick. Thanks so much, that makes a lot more sense than doing it to each element.